# Print values in pandas while inside if condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV that is read in as a dataframe. I have two questions.

1. How do I check multiple dfNetscn.Owner values within this condition? (i.e. msedge.exe, iexplorer.exe, firefox.exe)
2. How do I print the actual Owner name for the matching hits using the print function?

```py
dfNetscn = pd.read_csv (args.path +'/windows.netscn.NetScn.csv')

if len(dfNetscn[(dfNetscn.ForeignPort == "80") & (dfNetscn.Owner =="chrome.exe" )]) == 0:
    print("[!]Non browser HTTP/HTTPS network connection(s) detected!")
    print(dfNetscn.Owner.values[0])
```

CSV excerpt:

```
"TreeDepth","Offset","Proto","LocalAddr","LocalPort","ForeignAddr","ForeignPort","State","PID","Owner","Created"
0,"0xac818d494050","UDPv4","0.0.0.0",0,"",0,"",776,"lsass.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000 "
0,"0xac818d494050","UDPv6","::",0,"",0,"",776,"lsass.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000 "
0,"0xac818db931a0","TCPv4","0.0.0.0",135,"0.0.0.0",0,"LISTENING",496,"svchost.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db931a0","TCPv6","::",135,"::",0,"LISTENING",496,"svchost.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db932f0","TCPv4","0.0.0.0",49664,"0.0.0.0",0,"LISTENING",632,"wininit.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db93440","TCPv4","0.0.0.0",49664,"0.0.0.0",0,"LISTENING",632,"wininit.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db93440","TCPv6","::",49664,"::",0,"LISTENING",632,"wininit.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db93980","UDPv4","0.0.0.0",0,"",0,"",1180,"svchost.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
0,"0xac818db93ad0","UDPv4","0.0.0.0",0,"",0,"",1180,"svchost.exe","2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000 "
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a minimum reproducible example. Post an example input dataframe and an example output - need not be exactly original dataset, but representative of your dataset.

Comment: @SomeDude Just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are looking to get a summary of all unique values in the `Owner` column, you can use `dfNetscn["Owner"].unique()` to return an array you can iterate over.
2. You can select for rows that fulfil the conditions you want, then iterate over the rows to print the column values you need:

```py
selected_df = df[(df["ForeignPort"] == 0) & (df["Owner"] == "lsass.exe")]
print(selected_df)

#    TreeDepth          Offset  Proto LocalAddr  LocalPort ForeignAddr  ForeignPort State  PID      Owner                      Created
# 0          0  0xac818d494050  UDPv4   0.0.0.0          0         NaN            0   NaN  776  lsass.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000 
# 1          0  0xac818d494050  UDPv6        ::          0         NaN            0   NaN  776  lsass.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000
```